# Confusing about the Emacs custom system

Tags: emacs, elisp

There are several similar setting functions:

1. set & setq
2. set-default
3. defcustom
4. custom-set-value
5. custom-set-variables
6. customize-set-value
7. customize-set-variable

so, what's the difference between these functions?

If I want setting my own preferences to an add-on, for these scenario:

1. If a variable setting by defcustom, which setting-function will be better?
2. And what about a variable setting by defvar?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The short answer to you question is:

- use `setq` or `setq-default` for variables defined by `defvar`.
- use `setq`, `setq-default`, or the `Customize` mechanism for variables defined by `defcustom`

Below is the long answer.

The functions that you are going to use are the following:

- `set` is the main function to set the value of a variable.
- `setq` is another version that automatically quotes its first argument. This is useful since quoting the first argument is what you want to do almost all the time.
- Some variables cannot be set globally. Whenever you set the variable it is only set for the current buffer. If you want to simulate setting this variable globally you use `set-default` or `setq-default`.

The functions that a package writer uses are:

- `defvar` which allows the package writer to define a variable and to give some documentation. This function is not required but makes the life of users easier.
- `defcustom` builds on `defvar`. It tells emacs that it is a variable, and it allows the developer to create a `custom` interface to set the value. The developer can say, things like "this variable can contain only the value 'foo or 'bar".

Setting variables can be done two ways:

1. if `defvar` was used, the values can only be set by the user in its `.emacs` by using the `set` function (or variants)
2. if `defcustom` was used, the values can be set using `set` (see 1.) OR by using `Customize`. When using the customize mechanism, emacs will generate some code that it will place in `custom-set-variables`. The user should not use this function.

Comment: If the package writer does not use `defvar` but only `setq` then you can only override the value **after** you load the package. However you should never use `setq` without `defvar` in your package if the user can change the value. If you use a package written properly, there is no difference between using `setq` or `custom`.

Comment: This statement is not true. This is why I gave the explanation. You can `setq` anything you want anytime you want and it will not give an error. If `defvar` was used, then when the package is loaded `emacs` will realize a value was already set and will not take the default value given in `defvar`.

Comment: The errors that you can see before loading a package are happening if you use the content of the package to set the value, for example by using a function provided by the package. If you only set values with "normal" values such as strings you do not run into problems.

Comment: hmm, seems i was mistaken a bit about how that worked, thatnks

Comment: Another error that bit me in the past was trying to add elements to a list. If the package defines a standard list and I want to add to that list I need to wait for the package to be loaded (with `eval-after-load`) to add to the list, or copy the whole list and add my elements (which is what custom does).

Comment: Don't forget that a `setq` can assign to multiple variables, while `set` can only assign to one.

Answer (score 11):

They are, largely all paths to the same thing. There are some important differences though. The best way to get to know them is to read the manuals for Emacs and Elisp (see `C-h i)`. Off the top of the head though:

- `set` is a "low-level" variable assignment
- `(setq foo bar)` is shorthand for `(set (quote foo) bar)`
- `(set-default foo bar)` means "unless there is a more explicitly scoped definition of `foo` in the current buffer, use the value bar", and applies to all buffers.
- `defcustom` is used to mark a variable as one that the user is expected to be able to safely modify through the `customize` feature.
- `custom-set-value` and `customize-set-value` are two names that point to the same function.  They're convenience methods for working with the `customize` system.
- `custom-set-variables` and `customize-set-variables` are used to make some set of customized-through-customize variables active, IIRC.

In general, it's recommended to use `M-x customize` to change things around. You're free to set things defined with `defcustom` using `set` or `setq` in your `.emacs`, the customize system will warn you about it if you later change it via `customize` though.

`defcustom` is generally only used by people writing packages meant for distribution, and I don't think I've seen anyone use `custom-set-*` outside of files internal to customize. `setq` is very common in people's initialization files for setting things up how they like them, regardless of whether those things are marked for use with `customize` or not.

I don't have a full understanding of all this, hopefully someone else can shed more light, but I think that that's a fairly good overview :P

Comment: same answer, same appreciation.

Answer (score 7):

1. `set` and `setq` are the lowest level primitives used for assigning any kind of variable.
2. `set-default` and `setq-default` are emacs extensions that go along with buffer-local variables, to allow setting the default values used for new buffers.
   3-7. All the "custom" stuff is a later addition that was designed to support a user interface for managing variables that are intended to be used as user preferences.
3. `defcustom` is similar to `defvar`, but allows you to specify a place in the hierarchy of options, as well as data type information so that the UI can display the value as a menu, or automatically convert user input to the appropriate type.
4. I don't think there is a `custom-set-value` function.
5. `custom-set-variables` is used by the customize UI when saving all the user's options. It lists all the variables that the user has changed from their defaults.
   6-7. `custom-set-value` and `custom-set-variable` are used by the Customize UI to prompt the user for the current and default values of an option variable, and assign them. You don't normally call this yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Just as addition, the differences between those commands have increased due to the introduction of lexical binding, though those differences will not really be relevant if you just want to customize some variables.

The `def...` constructs *declare* global variables. The `set...` functions *set* variables, whether global or local. When `x` is neither a local variable (a formal parameter of the current function or declared by a `let` form or similiar) nor defined by a `def...` form and you write `(setq x 0)` the byte compiler will even show a warning

```
Warning: assignment to free variable `x'
```

Variables declared with `defvar`, `defcustom`, `defconst` are dynamically bound, i.e. when you have a construct

```
(let ((lisp-indent-offset 2))
  (pp (some-function)))
```

the function `some-function` will see the change of the global variable `lisp-indent-offset`.

When a variable is not dynamically bound, in something like

```
(let ((my-local-var 1))
  (some-function))
```

where `my-local-var` has no global value, then `some-function` will not see the assigned value, as it is lexically scoped.

On the other hand, dynamically scoped variables will *not* be captured into lexical closures.

More details can be seen in http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html

Comment: For clarity, unless lexical binding is *explicitly enabled* for a file, all variables will be dynamically bound, regardless of how they are defined and set.