# Emacs: Problems setting variables outside of customize section

Tags: emacs, elisp, markdown, emacs24

I'm having issues with setting markdown-command. I get symbol as a variable is void. I originally was setting inside of customize and had everything working. I wanted to clean up my init.el and I would rather keep everything outside of customize and set it manually.

Can anyone provide insight to this? Closest thing i have seen was here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058717/confusing-about-the-emacs-custom-system

Thanks.

```
    ;;General Settings
    (global-auto-revert-mode t) ;;Refresh Buffers on File Change.
    (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil) ;;Use spaces instead of tabs.
    (desktop-save-mode 1) ;;Save session
    (show-paren-mode 1) ;;Show matching parenthesis

    ;;Custom Load Paths
    (add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/") ;;Look here for additional themes.
    (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/modes/") ;;Look here for additional modes.


    ;;Load Specific Them
    (load-theme 'solarized-dark t)

    ;;Marmalade Package Manager
    (require 'package)
    (add-to-list 'package-archives 
        '("marmalade" .
          "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
    (package-initialize)

    ;;OSX Specific Settings
    ;;Add /usr/local/bin and /opt/local/bin to execution path
    (if (eq system-type 'darwin)
        (setq exec-path
              (append 
               '("/usr/local/bin"
                 "/opt/local/bin")
               exec-path)))


    ;;Markdown Specific Settings
    (autoload 'markdown-mode "markdown-mode"
       "Major mode for editing Markdown files" t)
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.text\\'" . markdown-mode))
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.markdown\\'" . markdown-mode))
    (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.md\\'" . markdown-mode))
     (if (eq system-type 'darwin)
        (setq-default 'markdown-command '("/usr/local/bin/pandoc"))
       (setq-default 'markdown-command '("/usr/bin/multimarkdown")))

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
)

(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

As per suggestion I tried

```
 (eval-after-load "markdown-mode"
 (if (eq system-type 'darwin)
 (setq markdown-command '("/usr/local/bin/pandoc"))
 (setq markdown-command '("/usr/bin/multimarkdown"))))
```

Then I realized my mistake. I hadn't done what was suggested.

```
    (eval-after-load "markdown-mode"
    (if (eq system-type 'darwin)
    '(setq markdown-command ("/usr/local/bin/pandoc"))
   '(setq markdown-command ("/usr/bin/multimarkdown"))))
```

Also as mentioned `eval-after-load "markdown-mode"` is not needed.

Comment: Use `(setq-default markdown-command ...)` instead `(setq-default 'markdown-command ..)`, it doesn't need quotation `'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *not* a great idea, in general:

> I originally was setting inside of customize and had everything working. I wanted to clean up my init.el and I would rather keep everything outside of customize and set it manually.

Yes, *keep Customize out of your init file*.  But that does *not* mean that you need to abandon use of Customize.  Use it for what it's good for.  And confine it to its own file, by defining option `custom-file`.

For your current problem, you do *not* need `eval-after-load` or any of the other code, to define this option the way you want it. You simply need to do `M-x customize-option RET markdown-command RET` and save the value after you update it --- in Customize.

This is the *right* way to customize user options.

Comment: Good to know. I am just beginning to learn best practices for Emacs.

Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

The code is failing because variable `markdown-command` is defined in `markdown-mode` and markdown-mode is not loaded yet. You can arrange for the variable to be set whenever `markdown-mode` is loaded by adding this to your init file.

```
(eval-after-load "markdown-mode"
  '(setq markdown-command '("/usr/bin/markdown")))
```

From <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`eval-after-load`<kbd>RET</kbd>

```
Arrange that if FILE is loaded, FORM will be run immediately afterwards.
If FILE is already loaded, evaluate FORM right now.
```

**UPDATE**

If you only wish to keep the customize options out of your init file you can add the following to your init file

```
(setq custom-file "~/your-custom-file")
(load custom-file)
```

Comment: Still having the same issue using your suggestion of:

 I put the change below the original code

Comment: @Snowrider: You forgot the quote (') before your `(if...)`.

Comment: I ended up getting it working and updated the original post. Thanks for the help guys and especially the tip about putting customize in its own file.

Comment: You do not need the `eval-after-when` if you have used Customize to define the value. That's the beauty of `defcustom`: you can set the variable's value before loading the library that defines the variable.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm to save your settings is like this: if the variable is customizable (look for the `You can customize this variable.` line at the bottom of the `*Help*` buffer for the variable), you put

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(markdown-command '("/usr/local/bin/pandoc"))
 '(indent-tabs-mode nil))
```

into your `.emacs`, otherwise you use `setq`.

When the package which uses your customization is actually loaded, it will set the variable correctly based on your `custom-set-variables` calls.

Comment: Or just click that `You can customize this variable` link and, well, customize it (and save the change). No need to fiddle with `custom-set-variables` at all.

Comment: @Drew: I don't think my command of English (or any other language) is adequate to express my disgust towards `customize`. Admittedly, it has been years since I gave it more than a cursory look, but I doubt anything substantial has been changed for the better.

Comment: Uh, okey dokey.  Whatever. ;-)

Comment: @Drew: no offense intended - to you or anyone else. This is a matter of taste. :-)

Comment: No worries -- no offense taken.  FWIW, I used to feel the same about Customize.  And of course I still feel that the UI leaves something to be desired.  But I think that `:type`, `:set`, and `:initialize` can help.  I've seen too much jumping through unnecessary hurdles because of the lure of avoiding Customize's self-proclaimed UI-for-dummies.  The real problem with Customize, I think, is that the code is difficult to work with -- hence little improvement gets done.  It was almost a write-only development, I'm afraid.